# Why does temperature have no uncertainity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

### Background

My understanding is that temperature is not a quantum mechanical operator. Hence, thereby it should not have any uncertainty. However, any instrument that tries to take the measurement of temperature will have some uncertainty in it for example the mercury postion of the thermometer! Further, we know temperature is 
$$ T = \frac{\partial U}{\partial S}_{(N,V)} $$

But we cannot measure $U$ with arbitrary accuracy so there must be some uncertainty in the slope of $U$ as well!

### Questions

Does temperaure have uncertainty? If yes, how is this possible when temperature is not a quantum mechanical observable? If no, how is this possible when it is the derivative of energy with respect to entropy and energy has uncertainty?

Comment: Ask yourself: Is temperature a quantum mechanical operator?

Comment: But the position of mercury or any thermometer instrument is a quantum mechanical operator ... right?

Comment: The intro of your question (about hamiltonians) has nothing to do with the question itself which is more or less: 'is the uncertainty of a reading on a mercury thermometer proportional to the uncertainty in the height of the mercury column'. The answer is clearyly 'yes'.

Comment: Okay, are you asking about the *experimental uncertainty of a temperature measurement*, or about the *fundamental uncertainty of a quantum mechanical observable*?

Comment: @ACuriousMind ... Hmm ... Didn't think about them as separately ... So if I understand your position correctly temperature is an exact quantity but the process whereby we measure will always have some experimental error (which is also unresolvable even by theoretical considerations)?

Comment: @jac the reason I wrote them the Hamiltonians is to highlight the fact that if like a typical quantum mechanical problem then I can obtain the temperature without the aid of even using say, Boltzmann's constant ...

Comment: The temperature of a system is just a measure of its energy, so it's subject to the same uncertainty as measuring the energy.

Comment: A canonically prepared system in equilibrium has a well defined temperature throughout (by definition!). As temperature is an ensemble property it is always stochastic but usually in the sense that even at a fixed temperature other quantities fluctuate.

Comment: @JohnRennie, temperature is not a measure of internal energy - there is no simple general relationship between the two. Internal energy also cannot be directly measured; but temperature can - there are no "energometers", but there are thermometers.

Answer (score 2):

The Heisenberg uncertainty principle applies to dimensions commensurate to $\hbar$, i.e. at the level of particles ( atoms, molecules, elementary particles). Temperature is a classical observable appearing in thermodynamics as a variable, but when analyzed from the emergent statistical ensemble it is not a variable but a [statistical average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature#Basic_theory) of the kinetic energy of the sample macroscopically displaying temperature $T$.

$$E_k=\frac12 m v^2_\mathrm{rms}=\frac32 kT$$

The formula above is for an ideal gas, but similar formulas exist for all bulk matter. Temperature is called an [intensive thermodynamic variable.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties)

As it is not a variable or a function/differential of variables at the quantum mechanical level, it cannot enter into the quantum mechanical equations as an operator. It thus cannot participate in the commutator relations that define whether an observable is limited, when measured, by the uncertainty principle.

Comment: No, that is not what temperature is. For example, the temperature of the electron gas in a metal is nowhere close to $kT$.

Comment: @Pieter  the fomula is for an ideal gas. Of course it will not hold for solids or whatever, but still temperature is an average statistical thermodynamic measure, emergent from the underlying quantum mechanical operator formulation .https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties it is an intensive property of bulk matter.

Comment: Actually, the formula also holds for solids (classical systems without zero point motion). But one can define temperature for a pure quantum system. like a spin system, counting states, determine the change with temperature. One can then order these systems in warmer and cooler, depending on the likely direction of energy transfer when they are in contact. Of course this is a bit of a toy system, but it is the same temperature as in the weather forecast.

Comment: @Pieter  I understood the question to be about the uncertainty principle, i.e. if there is an operator for the temperature with commutators defining uncertainty. There is another  answer  here where a link is given with the claim of temperature being a quantum mechanical operator, but commutators would be further down the line. this is the link to the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.09374   Temperature as a quantum observable . Rob deleted the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are extensions of temperature, I believe, for microscopical objets, but usual temperature is an intensive property of macroscopic objects. The number of degrees of freedom is at least Avogadro Number, and quantum effects tend to cancel.

You could perhaps as the question for mesoscopic objects.